# "NameError: [palavra que eu digitei] is not defined" ao tentar ler do teclado

Tags: python

Estava a seguir um pequeno tutorial. Fiz tudo exatamente como estava indicado no tutorial e deu me um erro de definição de variável ao passo que no tutorial não dava.

Alguém me pode explicar o erro?

Código:

```
print "hello wolrd"
myName = input("what is your name?")
myVar = "hello"
print (myName)
print (myVar)
```

Saída:

> ```
> C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop>python poop.py
> hello wolrd
> what is your name?Miguel
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "poop.py", line 2, in <module>
>     myName = input("what is your name?")
>   File "<string">, line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'Miguel' is not defined
> ```

A questão é que no tutorial quando punha o nome Miguel era suposto responder com Hello e não está a dar, alguém me pode explicar sff?

Comment: Use `raw_input` ao invés de `input`.

Comment: Olá e seja bem-vindo. Por favor, não coloque imagens com o seu código ou a saída de erros. Em vez disso, cole o conteúdo aqui. Isso facilita buscas futuras e permite a usuários de leitores de tela visualizarem o conteúdo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solução**:

Você está usando Python 2 e o tutorial deve estar usando Python 3. Use Python 3 ou troque `input` para `raw_input`.

**Explicação**:

A função `input` do Python 2 não é para ler strings, mas sim para ler alguma coisa do teclado e interpretá-la como códigos Python. É equivalente a `eval(raw_input())`. Como `Miguel` não está definido e parece o nome de uma variável, você recebe um erro de variável não definida.

Em Python 3, a função `input` agora se comporta como o `raw_input`, isso é, lê do teclado e retorna o valor como uma string.

A não ser que tenha bons motivos, já que está começando, recomendo aprender Python 3 e não Python 2. É o presente e o futuro da linguagem.

Comment: Ohhh thank you thank you!!